# Using COALESCE and Converting datetime fields

Tags: sql-server

I was given some code from a current user that I can't figure out how to convert to Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

```
,TO_CHAR( COALESCE( TASK.ACT_START_DATE, TASK.TARGET_START_DATE,
TASK.EARLY_START_DATE ), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI') 
    ||
COALESCE( NVL2( TASK.ACT_START_DATE, ' A', NULL), 
NVL2`enter code here`( TASK.TARGET_START_DATE, ' P', NULL), 
NVL2( TASK.EARLY_START_DATE, ' E', NULL))  AS START_DATE_FMT
```

The date fields have to be converted in order to add either an "A", "P" or an "E" behind the date.

Is there a way to use a similar code in SQL Server to get the information? I've considered using a CASE statement to validate for Null but can't get the syntax correct.

Comment: A CASE expression is the way to go.   Post your attempt to use CASE, and we can debug your syntax.

Comment: CASE WHEN TASK.ACT_START_DATE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' A' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),TASK.ACT_START_DATE,20)
  WHEN TASK.TARGET_START_DATE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' P' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19)TASK_TARGET_START_DATE,20)
  WHEN TASK.EARLY_START_DATE IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' E' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19) TASK.EARLY_START_DATE,20) 
  END AS START_DATE_FMT

Comment: A `CASE` expression can only have one `ELSE` clause.

Comment: Could you edit your question and put your attempted code in the question? comments do not work well for code and there is no formatting.

Comment: @GeomanYabes huh? There is one and only one else in a case expression. You can't have multiple ELSE clauses.

Comment: @GeomanYabes I've never seen anyone write ELSE WHEN in SQL Server.   Are you sure SQL Server supports it?   It's not in the documentation.   I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Maybe @GeomanYabes is referring to nested case expressions. Where you have ELSE CASE WHEN....

Comment: Maybe, or maybe there's some other language where ELSE WHEN is in the syntax.

Comment: sorry, my mistake.. @TabAlleman is correct. was confused with the multiple `WHEN` :D ill keep you posted once I already created a language where `ELSE WHEN` is the syntax XD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ISNULL on date column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240444/using-isnull-on-date-column)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
FORMAT( COALESCE( TASK.ACT_START_DATE, TASK.TARGET_START_DATE,TASK.EARLY_START_DATE ), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm') +
CASE WHEN TASK.ACT_START_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN ' A'
    WHEN TASK.TARGET_START_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN ' P'
    WHEN TASK.EARLY_START_DATE IS NOT NULL THEN ' E'
ELSE '' END AS START_DATE_FMT
```

Comment: Using the code above, I get an incorrect syntax error near the keyword COALESCE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option. Don't think you need a case expression here.

```
select 
FORMAT( COALESCE( TASK.ACT_START_DATE, TASK.TARGET_START_DATE,TASK.EARLY_START_DATE ), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm')
+ coalesce(' A' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19),TASK.ACT_START_DATE,20) 
    , ' P' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TASK_TARGET_START_DATE,20) 
    , ' E' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), TASK.EARLY_START_DATE,20))
```